# Is it possible to use emoji on A-Frame a-text?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I find it useful to use an emoji instead of an image in an `a-text`
But I tried this:

```
<a-text value="&#1F601"></a-text>
```

And this:

```
<a-text value=""></a-text>
```

And it doesn't seem to work (text is omitted).

And yes, it's included in head:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

Is it possible or is there a limitation with WebGL/ThreeJS/A-Frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have a font that comes with those glyphs. There are a bunch of fonts ready to use here: https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-fonts
I have not seen though anyone that includes emojis.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal way would be to have a bunch of emojis in a spritesheet and then use something like https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/atlas-uvs to represent them individually.

```
  <a-scene>
    <a-mixin id="emojis" atlas-uvs="totalRows: 4; totalColumns: 4" material="src: emojis.png" geometry="primitive: plane; buffer: false; skipCache: true"></a-mixin>

    <a-entity mixin="emojis" atlas-uvs="column: 1; row: 1"></a-entity>
    <a-entity mixin="emojis" atlas-uvs="column: 3; row: 2"></a-entity>
    <a-entity mixin="emojis" atlas-uvs="column: 2; row: 4"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks :) That's what I end up doing. I like the component!!